# Scrape forum using R

Tags: r

I would like to seek helping in scraping the information from hardware zone.

This is the link: http://www.hardwarezone.com.sg/search/forum/camera

I would like to get all the information on camera on the forum.

```
library(RSelenium)
library(magrittr)

base_url = "http://www.hardwarezone.com.sg/search/forum/camera"
checkForServer()
startServer()
remDrv <- remoteDriver()
remDrv$open()
```

I tried using the above codes for the first part, and I got an error for the last line. (Mac user)
The error I got is undefined RCurl call, but I referenced to many possible solutions but I still cannot solve it.

```
library (rvest)
url <- "http://www.hardwarezone.com.sg/search/forum/camera"
result <- url %>%
   html() %>%
   html_nodes (xpath = '//*[id="cse"]/table[1]') %>%
   html_table()
result
```

I tried using another method (Above code), but it still couldn't work.

Can anyone guide me through this?

Thank you.